# Add Current YTD / Total Last Year comparison columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two types of records: externals (acc), and internals (referred just as records).

Currently my query returns (acc) monthly totals, and (acc) totals from the date of implementation of the system (inception).

We now need to add total for (acc) Current YTD (separated by a '/' forward slash), Total of (acc) Last Year.

The same for the internal records which in the query are the columns [Last Month], and [Inception Count of Records].

Add total for (internal) Current YTD (separated by a '/' forward slash), Total of (internal) Last Year.

I think what I need to do is to add a few more sub-selects to get the numbers I need, but I am having trouble understanding how that part is structured and then used along what the columns that are already there.

I am including my current query that retrieves only current monthly total, and totals from the date of inception of both record types (external, and internal).

I hope all of this makes sense, because I would like to ask for some help so that I can complete this query. Any example or modification to my query, or some guidance would be awesome.

**Query** - *Revised WHERE clause and AND condition since using sample data already filtered (to certain degree)* -.

```
SELECT
    [RecordTypes].[Agency]                                                          [Agency]
,   [RecordTypes].[Record Type]                                                     [Record Type]
,   ISNULL([MonthlyRecords].[ACA], 0)                                               [ACA]
,   ISNULL([RecordTypes].[Inception Count ACA], 0)                                  [Inception Count ACA]
,   ISNULL([MonthlyRecords].[Count of Records], 0)                                  [Last Month]
,   [RecordTypes].[Inception Count of Records]                                      [Inception Count of Records]
,   ISNULL([RecordTypes].[Date of Last Record], '')                                 [Date of Last record]
,   ISNULL([RecordTypes].[Record Type Last Modified], '')                           [Date Record Type Last Modified]
,   IIF([RecordTypes].[ACA Enabled] IN ('VHAPP', 'VHSP', 'VHAI'), 'True', 'False')  [ACA Enabled]
FROM
    (SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN('Permitted Use Site Plan Review', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Conditional Use', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Planned Unit Development') THEN 'Zoning'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN ('Code Enforcement Mileage', 'Renewal Registration', 'Rental Property Emergency Contact', 'W&M License') THEN 'Building Inspection'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] IN ('Annexation', 'Condominium', 'Land Management', 'Land Use', 'Landmark', 'Subdivision') THEN 'Planning'          
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Equipment'               
                OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Vehicle'
                OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Facility'
                OR [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'As-Built Request'
                OR LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], 11) = 'Engineering' THEN 'Engineering'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'Edible Landscape Permit' THEN 'Mayor'                      
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'LICENSES' 
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection' THEN 'Building'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Traffic' THEN 'Traffic Engineering'
            WHEN LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], '7') = 'Streets' THEN 'Streets'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'AnimalServices' THEN 'Health'           
            ELSE [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE]
        END                             [Agency]
     ,  CASE
            WHEN [B1].[B1_PER_SUB_TYPE] NOT IN ('Landlord Registration', 'Foreclosure Registration')
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection'
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'Licenses' THEN 'License '+[R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS]
            ELSE REPLACE([R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS], '/NA', '')
        END                             [Record Type]
    ,   COUNT([B1].[B1_ALT_ID])         [Inception Count of Records]
    ,   COUNT([B1].[B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA])  [Inception Count ACA]
    ,   MAX([B1].[B1_FILE_DD])          [Date of Last Record]
    ,   MAX([R3].[REC_DATE])            [Record Type Last Modified]
    ,   MAX([R3].[R1_UDCODE3])          [ACA Enabled]
    FROM
        [R3APPTYP] [R3]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [B1PERMIT] [B1]
        ON [R3].[SERV_PROV_CODE] =          [B1].[SERV_PROV_CODE]
            AND [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] =       [B1].[B1_PER_GROUP]
            AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] =        [B1].[B1_PER_TYPE]
            AND [R3].[R1_PER_SUB_TYPE] =    [B1].[B1_PER_SUB_TYPE]
            AND [R3].[R1_PER_CATEGORY] =    [B1].[B1_PER_CATEGORY]          
    WHERE 
        [R3].[SERV_PROV_CODE] = 'MISOULA'
        AND [R3].[REC_STATUS] = 'A'
    GROUP BY
        CASE
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN('Permitted Use Site Plan Review', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Conditional Use', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Planned Unit Development') THEN 'Zoning'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN('Code Enforcement Mileage', 'Renewal Registration', 'Rental Property Emergency Contact', 'W&M License') THEN 'Building Inspection'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] IN('Annexation', 'Condominium', 'Land Management', 'Land Use', 'Landmark', 'Subdivision') THEN 'Planning'       
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Equipment'
                OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Vehicle'
                OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Facility'
                OR [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'As-Built Request'
                OR LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], 11) = 'Engineering' THEN 'Engineering'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'Edible Landscape Permit' THEN 'Mayor'      
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'LICENSES'
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection' THEN 'Building'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Traffic' THEN 'Traffic Engineering'
            WHEN LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], '7') = 'Streets' THEN 'Streets'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'AnimalServices' THEN 'Health'
            ELSE [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE]
        END
    ,   CASE
            WHEN [B1].[B1_PER_SUB_TYPE] NOT IN('Landlord Registration', 'Foreclosure Registration')
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection'
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'Licenses' THEN 'License '+[R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS]
            ELSE REPLACE([R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS], '/NA', '')
        END) 
            [RecordTypes]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN('Permitted Use Site Plan Review', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Conditional Use', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Planned Unit Development') THEN 'Zoning'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN('Code Enforcement Mileage', 'Renewal Registration', 'Rental Property Emergency Contact', 'W&M License') THEN 'Building Inspection'         
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] IN('Annexation', 'Condominium', 'Land Management', 'Land Use', 'Landmark', 'Subdivision') THEN 'Planning'           
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Equipment'               
                OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Vehicle'
                OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Facility'              
                OR [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'As-Built Request'
                OR LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], 11) = 'Engineering' THEN 'Engineering'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'Edible Landscape Permit' THEN 'Mayor'                               
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'LICENSES'
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection' THEN 'Building'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Traffic' THEN 'Traffic Engineering'
            WHEN LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], '7') = 'Streets' THEN 'Streets'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'AnimalServices' THEN 'Health'
            ELSE [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE]
        END [Agency]
     ,  CASE
            WHEN [B1].[B1_PER_SUB_TYPE] NOT IN ('Landlord Registration', 'Foreclosure Registration')
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection'
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'Licenses' THEN 'License '+[R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS]
            ELSE REPLACE([R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS], '/NA', '')
        END [Record Type]
     ,  COUNT([B1].[B1_ALT_ID]) [Count of Records]
     ,  COUNT([B1].[B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA]) [ACA]
     FROM
        [R3APPTYP] [R3]
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [B1PERMIT] [B1]
        ON [R3].[SERV_PROV_CODE] = [B1].[SERV_PROV_CODE]
            AND [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = [B1].[B1_PER_GROUP]
            AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = [B1].[B1_PER_TYPE]
            AND [R3].[R1_PER_SUB_TYPE] = [B1].[B1_PER_SUB_TYPE]
            AND [R3].[R1_PER_CATEGORY] = [B1].[B1_PER_CATEGORY]
            AND LEFT([B1_ALT_ID], 3) <> 'TMP'
            AND DATEPART([m], [B1].[B1_FILE_DD]) = DATEPART([m], DATEADD([m], -1, GETDATE()))
            AND DATEPART([yyyy], [B1].[B1_FILE_DD]) = DATEPART([yyyy], DATEADD([m], -1, GETDATE()))                   
     WHERE 
        [R3].[SERV_PROV_CODE] = 'MISOULA'
        AND [R3].[REC_STATUS] = 'A' 
     GROUP BY
        CASE
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN('Permitted Use Site Plan Review', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Conditional Use', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Planned Unit Development') THEN 'Zoning'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN('Code Enforcement Mileage', 'Renewal Registration', 'Rental Property Emergency Contact', 'W&M License') THEN 'Building Inspection'         
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] IN('Annexation', 'Condominium', 'Land Management', 'Land Use', 'Landmark', 'Subdivision') THEN 'Planning'           
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Equipment'
                OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Vehicle'
                OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Facility'
                OR [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'As-Built Request'
                OR LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], 11) = 'Engineering' THEN 'Engineering'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'Edible Landscape Permit' THEN 'Mayor'          
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'LICENSES'
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection' THEN 'Building'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Traffic' THEN 'Traffic Engineering'
            WHEN LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], '7') = 'Streets' THEN 'Streets'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'AnimalServices' THEN 'Health'
            ELSE [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE]
        END
     ,  CASE
            WHEN [B1].[B1_PER_SUB_TYPE] NOT IN('Landlord Registration', 'Foreclosure Registration')
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection'
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'Licenses' THEN 'License '+[R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS]
            ELSE REPLACE([R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS], '/NA', '')
        END) 
            [MonthlyRecords]     
    ON [RecordTypes].[Agency] = [MonthlyRecords].[Agency]   
        AND [RecordTypes].[Record Type] = [MonthlyRecords].[Record Type]
ORDER BY
    [RecordTypes].[Agency]
,   [RecordTypes].[Record Type];
```

**Table Definition - B1PERMIT**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B1PERMIT](
    [SERV_PROV_CODE] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [B1_PER_GROUP] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [B1_PER_TYPE] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [B1_PER_SUB_TYPE] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [B1_PER_CATEGORY] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [B1_FILE_DD] [datetime] NULL,
    [B1_ALT_ID] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA] [varchar](1) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Table Definition - R3APPTYP**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[R3APPTYP](
    [SERV_PROV_CODE] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [R1_PER_GROUP] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [R1_PER_TYPE] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [R1_PER_SUB_TYPE] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [R1_PER_CATEGORY] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [REC_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [R1_UDCODE3] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [REC_STATUS] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Sample Data - B1PERMIT**

```
MISSOULA    Permitting  Engineering Erosion Control NA  2018-07-16 00:00:00.000 ENG100-2017-04471   NULL
MISSOULA    Permitting  Engineering Sewer Plug  NA  2017-01-12 00:00:00.000 ENGSRP-2016-04904   NULL
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00001   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00003   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00004   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00007   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00009   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00012   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00014   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00017   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00021   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00022   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00024   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00028   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00030   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2017-01-03 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2017-00032   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00015   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-02 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00019   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-04 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00156   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00173   NULL
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00202   NULL
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-06 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00224   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-07 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00235   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-07 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00238   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-07 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00241   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-07 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00244   Y
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-08 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00257   NULL
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-08 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00258   NULL
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-08 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00259   NULL
MISSOULA    Permitting  Parks   DiscGolf    NA  2018-01-08 00:00:00.000 PRKDGP-2018-00260   NULL
```

**Sample Data - R3APPTYP**

```
    MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    Licenses    Civil Rights    AA Plan Exempt  2017-04-26 15:56:27.303 VHAPP   A   AA Plan Exemption (14 or fewer)
MISSOULA    _Enforcement    Building Inspection Housing Rental Prop Emergency Contacts  2018-02-26 16:36:45.987 NA  A   _Enforcement/Building Inspection/Housing/Rental Prop Emergency Contacts
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
MISSOULA    Land    Landmark    NA  NA  2018-04-18 09:13:50.787 VHAPP   A   Certificate of Appropriateness Application
```

Comment: Having table definitions and sample data would be really helpful. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ And pictures of data or output are not a great idea. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I think Everybody can help you easier if you show the sample data and expected output :))

Comment: you should be aware that your `AND LEFT([B1].[B1_ALT_ID], 3) <> 'TMP'` converts your LOJ to an Inner join.  If you want a LOJ, move the condition from the join to the `SELECT` for B1, like `(SELECT * from B1PERMIT WHERE  LEFT([B1].[B1_ALT_ID], 3) <> 'TMP') B1`

Comment: in general, try not to repeat calculations such as for `agency` and `record type`.  Try pulling everything you need from `R3APPTYP` in one query, applying whatever limiting criteria you're repeating and extending your columns with the calculation.  Same for querying `B1PERMIT`.  In general, you want to apply whatever you're repeating to an inner query instead of repeating it.

Comment: Thanks Beth, I am going to try to do that first. I will also upload some sample data and table definitions to make it easier to get help. Thanks again.

Comment: also, I think you'd be better off delaying your grouping and aggregation until your outermost query instead of LOJ a second copy of both base tables.  You can include your conditions for aggregation distinguishing last month's from inception rows with code like:

Comment: `(SELECT
   SERV_PROV_CODE, B1_PER_GROUP, B1_PER_TYPE, B1_PER_SUB_TYPE, B1_PER_CATEGORY,
   CASE            WHEN [B1_PER_SUB_TYPE] NOT IN ('R', 'L')   THEN 1        END isB1SubTypeNotRL,
   CASE WHEN 
    DATEPART([m], [B1_FILE_DD]) = DATEPART([m], DATEADD([m], -1, GETDATE()))             AND 
    DATEPART([yyyy], [B1_FILE_DD]) = DATEPART([yyyy], DATEADD([m], -1, GETDATE())) THEN 1 END AS isLastMonth
  FROM
   [B1PERMIT] 
  WHERE
   LEFT([B1_ALT_ID], 3) <> 'TMP'  ) [B1]`

Comment: then in your outermost query, do the aggregation once, but when you want last month's numbers, use `CASE when isLastMonth = 1` then <field> else 0 end`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179185/discussion-between-erasmo-carlos-and-beth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do it this way (without multiple subqueries):

```
WITH
  BaseData ([Agency], [Record Type], [B1_ALT_ID], [B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA], [B1_FILE_DD], [REC_DATE], [R1_UDCODE3], ThisYear, LastYear, LastMonth) AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN('Permitted Use Site Plan Review', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Conditional Use', 'Minor Alteration to Approved Planned Unit Development') THEN 'Zoning'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] IN ('Code Enforcement Mileage', 'Renewal Registration', 'Rental Property Emergency Contact', 'W&M License') THEN 'Building Inspection'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] IN ('Annexation', 'Condominium', 'Land Management', 'Land Use', 'Landmark', 'Subdivision') THEN 'Planning'          
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Equipment'               
              OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Vehicle'
              OR [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP]+'/'+[R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'AMS/Facility'
              OR [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'As-Built Request'
              OR LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], 11) = 'Engineering' THEN 'Engineering'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS] = 'Edible Landscape Permit' THEN 'Mayor'                      
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'LICENSES' 
                AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection' THEN 'Building'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Traffic' THEN 'Traffic Engineering'
            WHEN LEFT([R3].[R1_PER_TYPE], '7') = 'Streets' THEN 'Streets'
            WHEN [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'AnimalServices' THEN 'Health'           
            ELSE [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE]
        END [Agency]
     ,  CASE
            WHEN [B1].[B1_PER_SUB_TYPE] NOT IN ('Landlord Registration', 'Foreclosure Registration')
             AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] = 'Building Inspection'
             AND [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] = 'Licenses' THEN 'License '+[R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS]
            ELSE REPLACE([R3].[R1_APP_TYPE_ALIAS], '/NA', '')
        END [Record Type]
    ,   [B1].[B1_ALT_ID]
    ,   [B1].[B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA]
    ,   [B1].[B1_FILE_DD]
    ,   [R3].[REC_DATE]
    ,   [R3].[R1_UDCODE3]
    ,   CASE
          WHEN [B1].[B1_FILE_DD] >= DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
          THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END
    ,   CASE
          WHEN [B1].[B1_FILE_DD] >= DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
           AND [B1].[B1_FILE_DD] < DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
          THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END
    , CASE
        WHEN [B1].[B1_FILE_DD] >= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
         AND [B1].[B1_FILE_DD] < DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END

    FROM [R3APPTYP] [R3]
      LEFT OUTER JOIN [B1PERMIT] [B1]
        ON [R3].[SERV_PROV_CODE] =        [B1].[SERV_PROV_CODE]
          AND [R3].[R1_PER_GROUP] =       [B1].[B1_PER_GROUP]
          AND [R3].[R1_PER_TYPE] =        [B1].[B1_PER_TYPE]
          AND [R3].[R1_PER_SUB_TYPE] =    [B1].[B1_PER_SUB_TYPE]
          AND [R3].[R1_PER_CATEGORY] =    [B1].[B1_PER_CATEGORY]          

    WHERE [R3].[SERV_PROV_CODE] = 'MISOULA'
      AND [R3].[REC_STATUS] = 'A'
  )

SELECT
    [Agency]
,   [Record Type]
,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE LastMonth WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA] ELSE NULL END), 0)   [ACA]
,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE LastYear WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA] ELSE NULL END), 0)    [Last Year ACA]
,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE ThisYear WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA] ELSE NULL END), 0)    [YTD ACA]
,   ISNULL(COUNT([B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA]), 0)                                            [Inception Count ACA]
,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE LastMonth WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ALT_ID] ELSE NULL END), 0)          [Last Month]
,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE LastYear WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ALT_ID] ELSE NULL END), 0)           [Last Year Count of Records]
,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE ThisYear WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ALT_ID] ELSE NULL END), 0)           [YTD Count of Records]
,   ISNULL(COUNT([B1_ALT_ID]), 0)                                                   [Inception Count of Records]
,   ISNULL(MAX([B1_FILE_DD]), '')                                                   [Date of Last record]
,   ISNULL(MAX([REC_DATE]), '')                                                     [Date Record Type Last Modified]
,   IIF(MAX([R1_UDCODE3]) IN ('VHAPP', 'VHSP', 'VHAI'), 'True', 'False')            [ACA Enabled]

FROM BaseData
GROUP BY [Agency],  [Record Type]
ORDER BY [Agency],  [Record Type];
```

If you really need the TMP condition for the "last month" part, you can easily include it in the respective `CASE` expression.

**To combine the new fields (added)**

To combine the new fields and make them character strings, I suggest to - for simplicity - use another CTE. Add a **comma** behind the closing bracket of the first CTE (`BaseData`) and replace the `SELECT` statement by a second CTE and a final `SELECT` statement as follows:

```
  Results AS (
    SELECT
        [Agency]
    ,   [Record Type]
    ,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE LastMonth WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA] ELSE NULL END), 0)   [ACA]
    ,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE LastYear WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA] ELSE NULL END), 0)    [Last Year ACA]
    ,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE ThisYear WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA] ELSE NULL END), 0)    [YTD ACA]
    ,   ISNULL(COUNT([B1_ACCESS_BY_ACA]), 0)                                            [Inception Count ACA]
    ,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE LastMonth WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ALT_ID] ELSE NULL END), 0)          [Last Month]
    ,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE LastYear WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ALT_ID] ELSE NULL END), 0)           [Last Year Count of Records]
    ,   ISNULL(COUNT(CASE ThisYear WHEN 1 THEN [B1_ALT_ID] ELSE NULL END), 0)           [YTD Count of Records]
    ,   ISNULL(COUNT([B1_ALT_ID]), 0)                                                   [Inception Count of Records]
    ,   ISNULL(MAX([B1_FILE_DD]), '')                                                   [Date of Last record]
    ,   ISNULL(MAX([REC_DATE]), '')                                                     [Date Record Type Last Modified]
    ,   IIF(MAX([R1_UDCODE3]) IN ('VHAPP', 'VHSP', 'VHAI'), 'True', 'False')            [ACA Enabled]

    FROM BaseData
    GROUP BY [Agency],  [Record Type]
  )

SELECT
     [Agency]
  ,  [Record Type]
  ,  [ACA]
  ,  [Inception Count ACA]
  ,  CASE [YTD ACA]
       WHEN 0 THEN 'NA' ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), [YTD ACA])
     END 
     + N'/' + 
     CASE [Last Year ACA]
       WHEN 0 THEN 'NA' ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), [Last Year ACA])
     END [YTD/LY ACA]
  ,  [Last Month]
  ,  [Inception Count of Records]
  ,  CASE [YTD Count of Records]
       WHEN 0 THEN 'NA' ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), [YTD Count of Records])
     END 
     + N'/' + 
     CASE [Last Year Count of Records]
       WHEN 0 THEN 'NA' ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), [Last Year Count of Records])
     END [YTD/LY of Records]
  ,  [Date of Last record]
  ,  [Date Record Type Last Modified]
  ,  [ACA Enabled]

FROM Results
ORDER BY [Agency],  [Record Type];
```

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, I have not used CTE before, but let me study your example and see if I can make it work on my end. Thank you so much for your help on this task.

Comment: I have a question, how can I combine the new fields and rather than having 4, use newfield1/ new fields2, if the value is zero, then display "NA". Thank you.

Comment: Although this would be possible in my `SELECT` statement, we would have to repeat each new formula  at least twice, so I suggest to use another CTE. I 've just added that to my answer. CTEs can be used to build "recursive" queries,  but I also like to use them to make nested queries more readable. In my query above, they are like "named subqueries" that are defined above the query that uses them.

Comment: @Wolfang Kais, thank you so much for your help. Your query so far has worked the way I needed it. I truly appreciate your help. If I have anymore questions regarding this subject, I'll make sure to open a new question. Kind regards.

Comment: @erasmocarlos That's a great idea, and, you are welcome. It was fun to simplify your lengthy query. :-)